# Dynamic linq not working

Tags: linq, dynamic

I have a problem. I want to build a dynamic LINQ query like this:

```
 var result = from li in datacTx.LIs
                     where 
                           (((StartDate != null) && (StartDate.Date != DateTime.MinValue)) ? li.Available <= StartDate.Date : true) &&
                           (((EndDate != null) && (EndDate.Date != DateTime.MinValue)) ? li.Expire <= EndDate.Date : true)
                     select new
                         {
                             A,
                             B,
                             C,
                             D
                         };
```

Before calling this query I am intializing the StartDate and EndDate with:

```
        StartDate = DateTime.MinValue;
        EndDate = DateTime.MinValue;
```

The problem is that the branch of "if" is always wrong I never can get the "true" branch if the StartDate and EndDate are having MinValue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a simpler condition:

```
where ((StartDate == DateTime.MinValue || li.Available <= StartDate.Date) &&
       (EndDate == DateTime.MinValue || li.Expire <= EndDate))
```

However, if I were to implement something like this, I would actually create the query dynamically:

```
var query = datacTx.LIs;
if(StartDate != DateTime.MinValue)
    query = query.Where(li => li.Available <= StartDate.Date);
if(EndDate != DateTime.MinValue)
    query = query.Where(li => li.Expire <= EndDate .Date);

var result = query.Select(x => new { A, B, C, D });
```

Comment: This is not the result that I want to get. I want: if StartDate.Date != DateTime.MinValue the condition li.Available <= StartDate.Date to be included in "where" clause, if StartDate.Date == DateTime.MinValue I don't want to use this condition in "where" clause: li.Available <= StartDate.Date

Comment: @dpv: The outcome of the condition should be the same. Just walk through it with some values. Additionally, please see update.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. Your solution (second proposal) works great.